# How to set a custom chrome binary path for apparition driver?

Tags: capybara, apparition

I'm using [apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) together with [heroku-buildpack-google-chrome](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) configured as [`unstable`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome#channels) and I'm trying to specify a custom chrome binary path: `/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-unstable`.

Is there a way to do this in apparition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the environment variable `BROWSER_PATH` it will be used as the location of the Chrome binary.